# Link to specific coordinates within PDF?

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfbox, acrobat

As [http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html] shown, to add html link to specific page in a PDF document one writes

```
"http://www.example.com/myfile.pdf#page=4"
```

However if further we would like to link to specific coordinate within the PDF file, like (300, 500), is there a link scheme to achieve that?

Feng

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with:

```
"http://www.example.com/myfile.pdf#viewrect=left,top,wd,ht"
```

A complete list of all supported parameters can be found [here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#page=5&view=FitH,400). At least the viewer application has to support them! Anyhow I must admit that I just do not get the quoted one to work with the Adobe Reader XI... So maybe another one like #view=FitH,400 could work for you.

Comment: Could you try: https://www.adobe.com/misc/pdfs/sssheep_chptr3.pdf#page=5&viewrect=130,460,100,100  ? Works for me in Firefox which uses Acrobat as the PDF plugin. @Setasign

Comment: works using Acrobat as Firefox plugin, not with Foxit reader. @Setasign

Comment: Do you know how to open file locally with coordinates? likely we need to change "http://" into "file://", how can that be done?